# DataFrame New Column to split sessions by time difference - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, partition

I have following sorted DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

hits = {'id': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','C','C'],
        'datetime': ['2010-01-02 03:00:00','2010-01-02 03:05:10','2010-01-02 03:51:35','2010-01-02 04:40:20',
                    '2010-01-02 03:29:10','2010-01-02 03:29:15','2010-01-02 03:45:20','2010-01-02 06:10:05'],
        'value': [1,2,2,1,1,3,2,4]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(hits, columns = ['id', 'datetime','value'])

df['datetime'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print (df)


  id            datetime  value
0  A 2010-01-02 03:00:00      1
1  A 2010-01-02 03:05:10      2
2  A 2010-01-02 03:51:35      2
3  A 2010-01-02 04:40:20      1
4  B 2010-01-02 03:29:10      1
5  B 2010-01-02 03:29:15      3
6  C 2010-01-02 03:45:20      2
7  C 2010-01-02 06:10:05      4
```

The column `id` allows me to differentiate unique users, but I want to give a step forward and being able to group hits by sessions. One session is defined as all user activity without more than 30 minutes inactivity.

In my DataFrame, the desired output should be:

```
  id            datetime  value  session
0  A 2010-01-02 03:00:00      1        1
1  A 2010-01-02 03:05:10      2        1
2  A 2010-01-02 03:51:35      2        2
3  A 2010-01-02 04:40:20      1        3
4  B 2010-01-02 03:29:10      1        1
5  B 2010-01-02 03:29:15      3        1
6  C 2010-01-02 03:45:20      2        1
7  C 2010-01-02 06:10:05      4        2
```

In `SQL` I would first use `lag` to calculate the difference between hits over `partition by id order by datetime asc`, and then in a new query I would `sum(case when diff > 30min then 1 else 0 end)`, partitioned by id too.

Is something similar in Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common technique to use `cumsum` on `diff` compared with the threshold to identify blocks separated by threshold. Something like:

```
series.diff().gt('30Min').cumsum()
```

Since you want to find the blocks by id, you just need to wrap that in `groupby()`:

```
df['session'] = (df.groupby('id')['datetime']
                   .transform(lambda x: x.diff().gt('30Min').cumsum())
                )
```

Output:

```
  id            datetime  value  session
0  A 2010-01-02 03:00:00      1        0
1  A 2010-01-02 03:05:10      2        0
2  A 2010-01-02 03:51:35      2        1
3  A 2010-01-02 04:40:20      1        2
4  B 2010-01-02 03:29:10      1        0
5  B 2010-01-02 03:29:15      3        0
6  C 2010-01-02 03:45:20      2        0
7  C 2010-01-02 06:10:05      4        1
```

Comment: Awesome! Just a side question: How do you know the "30Min" trick? I can't find it in the [official docs of .gt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html).

Comment: @BillHuang can't quite remember when I learned that.

Comment: @BillHuang that kind of syntax is imilar in other date/time operations including `pd.Grouper`, `.asfreq()`, etc.

Comment: @DavidErickson `pd.Grouper.asfreq()` doesn't seem to exist in the docs either. Searching "datetime gt" also gave me seemly irrelevant results. Maybe it was once documented in version 0.x but got removed in 1.x?

Comment: @BillHuang I was using `Grouper` and `.asfreq` as two separate examples. The official documentation for `Grouper` and `.asfreq` each contain the following link within their documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases `Min` is  in that table. However, I have seen `min`, `m` and I believe `minutes` passed as well. Not all versions of pandas accept every string variation, as I remember answering a stackoverflow question in the past, and the person I was helping had an older version. `1m` didn't work but `1min` did.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a double `.groupby`:

1. You can create a `boolean series` called `s`that use `.groupby` on `id` and returns `True` or `False` for each row within each group if greater than 30 minutes.
2. Then, you can groupby on `id` again that you created in step 1 and return the cumulative count with `.cumsum` and add 1, so that you start counting at 1 instead of 0

---

```
df['session'] = (df.assign(session=(df.groupby('id')['datetime'].diff() > '00:30:00')
                                      .astype(int))
                   .groupby('id')['session'].cumsum() + 1)
Out[1]: 
  id            datetime  value  session
0  A 2010-01-02 03:00:00      1        1
1  A 2010-01-02 03:05:10      2        1
2  A 2010-01-02 03:51:35      2        2
3  A 2010-01-02 04:40:20      1        3
4  B 2010-01-02 03:29:10      1        1
5  B 2010-01-02 03:29:15      3        1
6  C 2010-01-02 03:45:20      2        1
7  C 2010-01-02 06:10:05      4        2
```